# Switch user from adaptive to desktop version of site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a desktop and adaptive (with media query in css) design of site. How can I show desktop version of my site if user come to it from mobile gadget? There is only idea in my head:

1. Set up cookie (for example `siteVersion = mobile)` previously.
2. If user choose desktop version (via clicking button, link...however) set up this cookie to "desktop" and after refresh page load css with desktop design.

Does anyone have other ideas? Maybe someone has someexperience with it?

Comment: You're doing something wrong here.  If you want an adaptive (responsive) website, then that already includes the desktop version of the website. There is no need to redirect mobile users at this point. Therefore, I'm confused about what you are asking.

Comment: I know well about adaptive principles and 'low' of adaptive construction and philosophy, but  i need to get a possibility to user choose wich design they are want to see and use.

Comment: Let's assume you have 2 different website designs and you want the user to choose a specific one to use.  If this is the case, you can use cookies to store the user's desired state.  If you are interested in implementing a solution using PHP, look into [PHP Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Answer (score 1):

So, what @jared gotte said - "adaptive" implies a web page that can adapt to the device capabilities without having to serve up different content from the server.  So in that regard your question is a bit nonsensical.

But, that said, the way most [large] sites handle serving different content to mobile .vs. desktop is by setting up different subdomains.  For example Facebook uses `www.facebook.com` for the desktop version of the site, and `m.facebook.com` for the mobile version.  When a user first hits the site, the server looks at the `User-Agent` header to decide what type of device they're using and redirects them appropriately.  If/when you want to switch them between the two on the client, you can use JS to [redirect their browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).

The caveat to this is that you'll need to setup the DNS hostname(s), and make your server code aware of the `Host` header on incoming requests.

Comment: I didn't have 2 different design. I've already have site with adaptive layout. I have an experience in developing of mobile and adaptive layout and I know about difference with this technologies. But I  didn't know how to switch user to desktop version from adaptive if user 'want' to visit it from mobile gadget.

Answer (score 1):

Put your desktop CSS in one CSS file.  Put your adaptive stuff in another CSS file.  Serve both to the user.  But then if a user says "show me the desktop version", stop serving them the adaptive CSS file.